# How to display an image of each category. Google Drive

Tags: laravel, google-drive-api

I store category images in Google Drive. The category in the database stores the name of the image, the same as the name of the image in Google Drive. By this name, I get the url of the image and display it in the category column. However, I cannot think of how to make sure that each category/subcategory has its own picture. Now all I have achieved is that the categories and subcategories have different pictures, but all categories have the same picture, and so do the subcategories.

```
public function compose(View $view)
  {
      $catalog = Category::with('children')->where('parent_id', '=', NULL)->get();
      //
      foreach ($catalog as $cat) {
        if(isset($cat->img)){
            $contents = collect(Storage::disk('google')->listContents('askldjfDSKLsOe2sdlKJF/', false));
            $file = $contents
            ->where('type', '=', 'file')
            ->where('filename', '=', pathinfo($cat->img, PATHINFO_FILENAME))
            ->where('extension', '=', pathinfo($cat->img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))
            ->first();
        };
        $catimg = collect(isset($cat->img)?(isset($file['path'])?(Storage::disk('google')->exists($file['path'])?Storage::disk('google')->url($file['path']):NULL):NULL):NULL);
        foreach ($cat->children as $subcat) {
          if(isset($subcat->img)){
              $contents = collect(Storage::disk('google')->listContents('askldjfDSKLsOe2sdlKJF/', false));
              $file = $contents
              ->where('type', '=', 'file')
              ->where('filename', '=', pathinfo($subcat->img, PATHINFO_FILENAME))
              ->where('extension', '=', pathinfo($subcat->img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))
              ->first();
          };
          $subcatimg = collect(isset($subcat->img)?(isset($file['path'])?(Storage::disk('google')->exists($file['path'])?Storage::disk('google')->url($file['path']):NULL):NULL):NULL);
        };
      };
      return $view->with(['catalog' => $catalog, 'catimg' => $catimg, 'subcatimg' => $subcatimg]);
  }
```

View:

```
<ul>
 @foreach( $catalog as $item )
  <li class='has-sub'><a href="#"><img class="catalogimg" src="@if($item->img != NULL && $catimg != NULL){{$catimg}}@else /img/categories/kitchen-utensils.png 
  @endif"><span class="cat-text">{{ $item->name }}</span></a>
   <ul>
    @foreach( $item->children as $subitem )
     <li><a href='/{{ $subitem->url }}/{{ $subitem->url }}'><img class="catalogimg" src="@if($subitem->img != NULL && $subcatimg != NULL){{$subcatimg}}@else /img/categories/kitchen-utensils.png @endif"><span class="cat-text">{{ $subitem->name }}</span></a></li>
    @endforeach
   </ul>
  </li>
 @endforeach
</ul>
```

Category Model:

```
public function children()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

Comment: In your DB, do all categories have unique filenames or are they the same (maybe because you seeded them so). Because I don't think there is a problem in your code that won't let you get the right url

Comment: Each picture has a unique name. The point is different, how to take a collection of these urls to images from the controller(View Composers in my case), and transfer them to the view, so that each category has its own personal image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I understand your problem now. You can simply create a new field in your array/collections, I call it `img_url`. Save the respective URL into this field and access it later.

```php
public function compose(View $view)
{
 foreach ($catalog as $cat) {
    $catimg = null; //define it here as null
        if(isset($cat->img)){
            $contents = collect(Storage::disk('google')->listContents('askldjfDSKLsOe2sdlKJF/', false));
            $file = $contents
            ->where('type', '=', 'file')
            ->where('filename', '=', pathinfo($cat->img, PATHINFO_FILENAME))
            ->where('extension', '=', pathinfo($cat->img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))
            ->first();
            
             $catimg = collect(isset($file['path'])?(Storage::disk('google')->exists($file['path'])?Storage::disk('google')->url($file['path']):NULL):NULL);
        };
        $cat['img_url'] = $catimg; // create a new field called img_url and assign value
        foreach ($cat->children as $subcat) {
          $subcatimg = null;
          if(isset($subcat->img)){
              $contents = collect(Storage::disk('google')->listContents('askldjfDSKLsOe2sdlKJF/', false));
              $file = $contents
              ->where('type', '=', 'file')
              ->where('filename', '=', pathinfo($subcat->img, PATHINFO_FILENAME))
              ->where('extension', '=', pathinfo($subcat->img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))
              ->first();
              $subcatimg = collect(isset($file['path'])?(Storage::disk('google')->exists($file['path'])?Storage::disk('google')->url($file['path']):NULL):NULL);
          };
      $subcat['img_url'] = $subcatimg;
        };
      };
      return $view->with(['catalog' => $catalog]);
}
```

View:

```php
<ul>
 @foreach( $catalog as $item )
  <li class='has-sub'><a href="#"><img class="catalogimg" src="@if(!is_null($item->img_url)){{$item->img_url}}@else /img/categories/kitchen-utensils.png 
  @endif"><span class="cat-text">{{ $item->name }}</span></a>
   <ul>
    @foreach( $item->children as $subitem )
     <li><a href='/{{ $subitem->url }}/{{ $subitem->url }}'><img class="catalogimg" src="@if(!is_null($subitem->img_url)){{$subitem->img_url}}@else /img/categories/kitchen-utensils.png @endif"><span class="cat-text">{{ $subitem->name }}</span></a></li>
    @endforeach
   </ul>
  </li>
 @endforeach
</ul>
```

In your view access the image urls like: `$item->img_url` or `$subitem->img_url`, it is possible that this value is null, but that shouln't be a problem per se.

Comment: So I shouldn't pass the $catimg and $subcatimg variables? If it doesn't bother you, could you update the question and give the full code of the controller and view? It seems that I am confused somewhere and am doing something wrong.

Comment: @vcxbgfx I made the edits, let me know if something is still unclear

Comment: Your code works. Thank you! And I got confused that when I created the question, the folder ID did not set the real value, but random symbols, and forgot to change it, so I got an error))) Now it seems like a link appears, but for some reason, for example, instead of `"https://url.com"`, the output is `"["https://url.com"]"`. That is, two more square brackets and quotes. This is probably due to the array?

Comment: This happened because you called `collect(...)`, this made a collection of your url, which you overrode in each iterattion. So you still had only one item in the collection. In your view, to display the collection it is transformed into the array like structure. @vcxbgfx